# Node.js: is there a way for cross-platform write of line endings (aka 'text mode' in C++/Pascal)?

Tags: node.js, file-io, cross-platform, line-endings, fs

I know very useful routine `fs.writeFileSync`. Unfortunatelly, if I pass newline (`\n`) to it, it writes one character only - `\x0A` both on Windows and Linux (and, I guess, on Mac). In C/C++ we can open file in 'text mode', when standard library converts `\n` to OS-specific line endings on-the-fly both for reading and writing. Is there any analog for Node? Of course I can manually replace all `\n` by `os.EOL`, but I don't like that much.

Comment: There's a way to pass the flags to the underlying `open` call (via `options`) but I can't tell if they explicitly pass the binary flag, or whether there's a way to override and specify the text flag.